# npm Yo (Yeoman) package no longer working?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yo

It appears YO is corrupted?

I can successfully run -> npm install -g yo
and it returns

Everything looks all right!

yet something triggered and the yo command now returns

'yo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I think it started happening after I installed Facebook's npm flux package.

I don't know if I should have avoided doing that?  If that is even relative...  If I'm missing something easy...

Thanks

Comment: Have a look into `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` you should see `yo` and `yo.cmd` if it's not there reinstall yeoman. If it is there then you have a problem with `PATH`. Run `path` in command line and check there is `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm;`

Comment: yo and yo.cmd are there, but I have no path to npm and a weird path to node_modules

Comment: `c:\>path
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;./node_modules/.bin`

I tried 

`c:\>setx path "%path%;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm`

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

yet it doesn't show in path

Comment: Stupid mistake sorry.  fixed the path.